# Java Why Does a conversion from byte to char require explicit cast?

Tags: java, types

Why does a conversion from byte to char require an explicit cast?

```
byte bByte = 65;
char cChar = (char)bByte;
```

As you can see here the type byte is smaller than the char but I still do need to do an explicit cast? Why is that? Can anybody explain me?

Comment: Why you need to convert a byte to a Char?

Comment: You may be surprised by the value of `(int) (char) (byte) -1` (it's 65535). Short answer: `char` is unsigned; none of Java's other numeric types are.